# How to calculate running balance on scheduled loan repayment based on customer payment using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a scheduled loan repayment MySql table with a customer loan payment.

The code below logic is what I have tried but I don't seem to get it right. 
I will Appreciate Any help.
Thanks in advance.

```
$sql11 = "SELECT * FROM loan_paymentss WHERE borrower_loan_id = '$loan_id' ";

$result11 = mysqli_query($link,$sql11);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result11);
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result11)) {

    $id = $row2['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM loan_paymentss WHERE borrower_loan_id = '$loan_id' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $amt = $row1['amount'];
        $pmnt = $row1['pmnt_made'];
        $r = $amt-$amt_paid;
        for ($i=0; $i <= $count ; $i++) {

            if ($r == 0) {

                $pmnt = $amt_paid;
                $sql1 = "UPDATE loan_paymentss SET pmnt_made = '".$pmnt."', status='PAID' WHERE id = '$id' ";
                mysqli_query($link,$sql1);

            }elseif ($r > 0 ) {
                $pmnt = $amt_paid;
                $sql1 = "UPDATE loan_paymentss SET pmnt_made = '".$pmnt."', status='UNPAID' WHERE id = '$id' ";
                mysqli_query($link,$sql1);

            }else{
                if ( stristr($r,'-') ) {
                    $sql2 = "UPDATE loan_paymentss SET pmnt_made = '$r'  WHERE id = (select max(id) from loan_paymentss where id < '$x')";
                    mysqli_query($link,$sql2);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a form that accepts user payment and user can pay before or after loan payment scheduled but will be penalised for late payment after loan maturity date.

```
id|borrower_id|borrower_loan_id|payment_sched|  payment_number|amount| pmnt_made|status
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 34        |l_5261          |10/10/2019   |  1             |400   |          |UNPAID
2 | 34        |l_5261          |10/11/2019   |  2             |400   |          |UNPAID


When a customer pays $500 
Expected Output

1 | 34        |l_5261          |10/10/2019   |  1             |400   |   400     |PAID
2 | 34        |l_5261          |10/11/2019   |  2             |400   |   100     |UNPAID

When a customer pays $300

1 | 34        |l_5261          |10/10/2019   |  1             |400   |    300    |UNPAID
2 | 34        |l_5261          |10/11/2019   |  2             |400   |    0.00   |UNPAID

when a customer pays all installment @ a go
1 | 34        |l_5261          |10/10/2019   |  1             |400   |    400    |PAID
2 | 34        |l_5261          |10/11/2019   |  2             |400   |    400    |PAID
```

What am trying to achieve is whenever a customer pays a loan based

on scheduled payment(monthly installment eg. monthly installment of
 $400 for two terms)which a customer can decide to pay before or after

the scheduled date (eg. 10/10/2019 and 10/11/2019) so I want to update column pmnt_made(payment made withholds 0.00 initially) with the amount paid by customer and change status to "PAID" based on the ff conditions...

Instances
If first payment made (pmnt_made) is equal to amount(scheduled amount to be paid) update status to "PAID"
OR
If the first payment made (pmnt_made) is greater than  amount(scheduled amount to be paid) update status to "PAID" and subtract(amount - pmnt_made = -r) place value r in the next scheduled payment i.e 2nd scheduled pmnt_made, if r matches 
the first condition, update status to "PAID",if not wait for next payment
OR
if pmnt_made is less than amount(scheduled amount to be paid) don't update status but upon next payment(pmnt_made + new payment(pmnt_made) )if still less than the amount don't update status but if equal to (amount) go ahead and update status...

Comment: Can you explain what the actual problem is - we can see some code and some data samples but you have not clearly explained the issue or what the code doesn't do properly.

Comment: Your code looks to be vulnerable to `SQL Injection` though the use of embedded variables in the sql statements. As you are using `mysqli` you really, really ought to modify your code to use `prepared statements` - especially if this is to be a live system dealing with peoples finances - to do otherwise might be deemed neglectful!

Comment: I have updated what I want to achieve...

Comment: Pls I need help on this problem...

Comment: Can you explain: Why do you use `limit 1` on initial query? Why two records  - does that indicate that 2 (re)payments have been agreed or are expected? Each amount in the `amount` column is the agreed (re)payment amount?

Comment: How do you record when a payment is made? How do you record the penalty charged for late payments? Would a penalty incurred on 1st expected repayment data be added to expected payment amount for the next repayment date?

Comment: Limit 1 is to select the first record of the payment schedule for a customer/ borrower when he/she pays ...

Comment: Why two records - does that indicate that 2 (re)payments have been agreed or are expected? Yes

Comment: Each amount in the amount column is the agreed (re)payment amount?  Yes

Comment: How do you record when a payment is made? When payment is made an update(amount) with the amount paid for the first schedule and if the amount paid is greater than the scheduled amount, update the next scheduled payment with the balance from first payment.

Comment: How do you record the penalty charged for late payments? late payment penalty is initialized at the last scheduled payment.

Comment: Would a penalty incurred on 1st expected repayment data be added to expected payment amount for the next repayment date?  No at the last scheduled payment.